# How to prevent special character combinations cheating my login process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

My login form works fine unless the user passes strings like '1 or 1'  or '1'='1' which ignores the login process and validate the user anyway.

Here is my client side code.

```
$scope.user_login=function(){
    if($scope.user_name==''){
        alert('user name filed should not keep blank');
        loginField.borderColor('txtname');
    }else if($scope.user_pass==''){
        alert('password filed should not keep blank');
        loginField.borderColor('txtpwd');
    }else{
        var userData={'user_name':$scope.user_name,'user_pass':$scope.user_pass};
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "php/Login/login.php",
            data: userData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log('login',response);
            //alert("aa"+response.data['msg']);
            if(response.data['user_type']=='1'){
            $location.path('dashboard');
            }

        },function errorCallback(response) {
            //alert(""+response.data['msg'].length);
            if(response.data['msg'].length > 0)
                alert(response.data['msg']);
            $scope.user_name=null;
            $scope.user_pass=null;
        });

    }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: So you want this 1 to act something like a cheat code?

Comment: All cheat codes `1` and `'1` and `1`' and `'1'='1'`   ?

Comment: @CharlieH : Actually when i am typing total `1' or '1' = '1' or '1` value the page is getting login.

Answer (score 0):

This is sql injection. It should be prevented in your `login.php`.

Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) article and use the techniques described in it to solve your problem.

Here is an SO question about this:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)